# The white car is ____ more expensive than the green

Tags: adverbs, exam-questions, comparative-constructions

> The white car is _________ more expensive than the green

> (Options: very, pretty, fairly, slightly).

The answer given is ***slightly***. Could you explain why this option is given as the correct one and others are not?

***More expensive*** is an adjective. And I think ***very, pretty, fairly and slightly*** are adverbs. So to describe this adjective, can we also use the adverbs ***very*** and ***pretty***,  instead of ***slightly***?

As I entered this in a grammar correction tool it indicated I should use ***much*** as a quantifier after *pretty*. i.e.

> The white car is ***pretty much more expensive***...

Is this is correct?

Comment: Never trust grammar checkers.  None of them are very good.

Comment: We can say _much more_ and _slightly more_, but we can't say _very more, pretty more_ or _fairly more_. We can say _very much more_, but _pretty much more_ sounds odd.

Comment: ***slightly, somewhat, much, a bit*** are all valid before ***more** [expensive, whatever]*. But ***very, pretty, fairly*** can't be used in conjunction with ***more*** in a comparative context - a thing can be ***fairly big***, but it can't be ***fairly bigger** [than something else].* Note that in such contexts, ***slightly*** modifies ***more***, not ***expensive***.

Comment: ...but in ***very expensive***, the "intensifier" ***very*** directly modifies the main adjective ***expensive*** - it can't be used to modify the "comparative" ***more*** (but it can be used in the sequence ***very much more expensive***, where ***very*** modifies ***much***, which itself modifies ***more***).

Comment: Remember, ELL folks -- however you use a grammar checker in your own language is just how you should use it in English. English is just another language and so English grammar checkers suck just as much as the ones in your native language.

Answer (score 2):

First, *adverbs of degree* before another adverb **will modify that adverb only**, not the whole phrase that the adverb is a part of. So, while "more expensive" is an *adjective phrase*, all of the possible answer words only modify the comparative adverb "more".

Second, although all the answer words are adverbs, different types of adverbs have different rules about what they can modify. *Slightly* can modify the *comparative adverb* "more", while *very, pretty,* and *fairly* cannot.

So, "slightly" correctly modifies "more", while the other words make for bad grammar. Other adverbs that have similar functions and rules to "slightly" include "a lot", "much", "somewhat", and "no", among others.